# convert string to array of cllocationcoordinate2d swift

Tags: swift

I am using an API that returns a `String` that contains coordinate. How do I convert this response:

> "route_pins":
>   "#30.0539983,30.943465#30.0539033,30.9434167#30.05379,30.9434467#30.0536117,30.943865#30.0535133,30.9439867#30.0534633,30.9440967#30.05353,30.94428#30.053675,30.944525#30.0539933,30.9449667#30.0541517,30.9452317#30.0542917,30.9454717#30.054365,30.9455717#30.0544667,30.945725#30.05471,30.9460733#30.0548667,30.94631#30.0550417,30.9465683#30.0553733,30.9471133#30.0557133,30.9476383#30.0558667,30.947905#30.0560083,30.9481767#30.0562517,30.94872#30.0564917,30.9492217#30.0565783,30.9494567#30.056645,30.9496883#30.0566167,30.9501883"

into an `Array` of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to draw a line using `MapKit` using:

```
let polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: Locations , count: Locations.count)
busMapView.add(polyLine)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `components(separatedBy` and `map`

- Split the string by character `#` and drop the first (empty) item.
- Map each item to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` by splitting the string by the comma, convert the strings to `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and create the coordinate.

---

```
let routePins = "#30.0539983,30.943465#30.0539033,30.9434167#30.05379,30.9434467#30.0536117,30.943865#30.0535133,30.9439867#30.0534633,30.9440967#30.05353,30.94428#30.053675,30.944525#30.0539933,30.9449667#30.0541517,30.9452317#30.0542917,30.9454717#30.054365,30.9455717#30.0544667,30.945725#30.05471,30.9460733#30.0548667,30.94631#30.0550417,30.9465683#30.0553733,30.9471133#30.0557133,30.9476383#30.0558667,30.947905#30.0560083,30.9481767#30.0562517,30.94872#30.0564917,30.9492217#30.0565783,30.9494567#30.056645,30.9496883#30.0566167,30.9501883"

let coordinates = routePins.components(separatedBy: "#").dropFirst().map { (pin) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
    let latLng = pin.components(separatedBy: ",").map{ CLLocationDegrees($0)! }
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latLng[0], longitude: latLng[1])
}
```

The result is `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]`.

Comment: This is exactly what i need..Thank you so so so much MR.Vadian You Just Saved Me Thank You So Much

Comment: `let latLng = pin.components(separatedBy: ","). compactMap(CLLocationDegrees.init)`

Answer (score 1):

```
let dic:Dictionary<String,Any> = ["route_pins": "#30.0539983,30.943465#30.0539033,30.9434167#30.05379,30.9434467#30.0536117,30.943865#30.0535133,30.9439867#30.0534633,30.9440967#30.05353,30.94428#30.053675,30.944525#30.0539933,30.9449667#30.0541517,30.9452317#30.0542917,30.9454717#30.054365,30.9455717#30.0544667,30.945725#30.05471,30.9460733#30.0548667,30.94631#30.0550417,30.9465683#30.0553733,30.9471133#30.0557133,30.9476383#30.0558667,30.947905#30.0560083,30.9481767#30.0562517,30.94872#30.0564917,30.9492217#30.0565783,30.9494567#30.056645,30.9496883#30.0566167,30.9501883"]


let strLatLng = dic["route_pins"] as! String
let arrayOflatLng = strLatLng.components(separatedBy: "#")
var testcoords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
for latLngStr in arrayOflatLng {
    if let strLat = latLngStr.components(separatedBy: ",") as? [String], strLat.count == 2 {
        testcoords.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(strLat[0])!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(strLat[1])!))
     }
}

print("testcoords \(testcoords.count)")
let polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: testcoords , count: testcoords.count)
busMapView.add(polyLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

The API string is parsed using 2 levels of parsing ,first we split the API string to locations strings , then using for loop to split each location to its coordinates and save coordinates to CLLocationCoordinate2D and append it to result array

```
  let routePins = "#30.0539983,30.943465#30.0539033,30.9434167#30.05379,30.9434467#30.0536117,30.943865#30.0535133,30.9439867#30.0534633,30.9440967#30.05353,30.94428#30.053675,30.944525#30.0539933,30.9449667#30.0541517,30.9452317#30.0542917,30.9454717#30.054365,30.9455717#30.0544667,30.945725#30.05471,30.9460733#30.0548667,30.94631#30.0550417,30.9465683#30.0553733,30.9471133#30.0557133,30.9476383#30.0558667,30.947905#30.0560083,30.9481767#30.0562517,30.94872#30.0564917,30.9492217#30.0565783,30.9494567#30.056645,30.9496883#30.0566167,30.9501883"
        let pins = routePins.components(separatedBy: "#")//first step is splitting the fetched array to pins array 
        var LocationsArray = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()//this is the result array
        for location in pins {
        if(location.contains(",")){//checking that the location is containing lat ,long separtor
        let coordinates = location.components(separatedBy: ",")//splitting the location to lat ,long 
        //safe parsing the string value to double vale for coordinates 
        let lat = Double(coordinates[0]) ?? 0.0
        let long = Double( coordinates[1]) ?? 0.0
        LocationsArray.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat
        ,longitude: long))// appending new coordinates to locations array
        }
        }
```

Comment: Try adding some context to your code to help future readers better understand its meaning.